# Does struct tm->tm_yday give correct value for leap year?

Tags: c, time

Say I want to get the days that have passed since Jan 1, would this return the correct value for leap years?

```
struct tm *now_tm;
struct timeval tv;
time_t currtime;

gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
currtime=tv.tv_sec;
now_tm = localtime(&currtime);
int day = now_tm->tm_yday;
```

tm reference
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would, if you initialize `currtime` to the current time instead of leaving it uninitialized:

```
time_t currtime = time(0);
```

A better reference will (probably) be found on your machine as `man localtime`. Or you can read it [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3p.html).

Note that the field is documented as having the values 0-365 (inclusive), not 0-364, so it has 366 possible values.

Comment: @schwern: it is guaranteed to work if you have a correct declaration of the `time` function (which is also required order to get the correct return value type).

Comment: My mistake, constant 0 is the null pointer. I got it mixed up with zeroing memory like `calloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you can test it. You're better off doing it with `gmtime` because `localtime` involves time zones and time zones can throw off the day by a day and we don't need that complication.

2000 was a leap year, and a tricky one, so it makes a good test. Unix epoch for midnight Jan 1st, 2000 UTC is 946684800 (30 years + 7 leap days from Jan 1st, 1970). So we move forward 31 + 28 days to Feb 29th. We can use `gmtime` to get the day of year, and `asctime` to verify we have the right date.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct tm *date;
    const int secs_per_day = 24 * 60 * 60;

    /* Jan 1st, 2000 midnight UTC in Unix epoch.
       30 years since Jan 1st, 1970.
       Plus 7 leap days between Jan 1, 1970 and Jan 1, 2000.
       Feb 29th 1972, 76, 82, 86, 92, and 96
    */
    int days = (30 * 365) + 7;
    time_t time = days * secs_per_day;

    date = gmtime(&time);
    printf("%d == %s", date->tm_yday, asctime(date));

    /* Jump ahead to Feb 29th */
    time += (31 + 28) * secs_per_day;

    date = gmtime(&time);
    printf("%d == %s", date->tm_yday, asctime(date));
}
```

And we can see it works, Feb 29th, 2000 is the 59th (counting from 0) day of the year.

```
0 == Sat Jan  1 00:00:00 2000
59 == Tue Feb 29 00:00:00 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it will return 365.  The 1st January will return 0, 31 December will return 364 for non-leap years and 365 for leap years