# A class for date and time representation in C++11

Tags: c++, datetime, c++11

I need a Class able to store date and time information in UTC (no timezone/locale required) and I also need to perform basic arithmetic operations on those date/times (addition, subtraction) and comparison. Ideally I would like use the C++11 standard library, if that is possible.

`std::chrono` seems a good candidate for my purposes. My `DateTime` class could be as simple as an alias of `chrono::time_point` with the desired precision. e.g.

`using UTCTime = std::chrono::time_point<SomeClock>;`

Defining a custom clock (`SomeClock`) allows my class to be type safe, while`chrono::time_point` class provides the computational requirements.

The missing piece of the puzzle are the functions to convert to/from date and time information. `chrono::system_clock` offers the methods `to_time_t` and `from_time_t`, which are limited by the precision of seconds, which is not good enough for me.

Does anybody have a solution for that?

Comment: I don't know if this may help: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: It's "basically" what you have in C++20's `<chrono>` but available as a single header library for your C++11 project.

Comment: How about the good old [`tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm)? If you need sub-second precision, you can store a number of (milli?)seconds next to the date, and manipulate it manually.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, for storing the data it would work fine. However I would lose the  arithmetic/operations/type safety  that `chrono::time_point` brings

Comment: Type-safety yes, but arithmetic can be done by converting to a `time_t` and back to fix any out-of-range fields.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237966/does-struct-tm-tm-yday-give-correct-value-for-leap-year) may help? I use a wrapped version of `boost gregorian` for dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot use C++20 I ended up with this C++11 minimal `std::chrono` based implementation:

`utctime.h`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

struct UTCClock
{
  typedef std::chrono::microseconds duration;
  typedef duration::rep rep;
  typedef duration::period period;
  typedef std::chrono::time_point<UTCClock, duration> time_point;
  static const bool is_steady = true;

  //      
  // every time_point will be generated from here
  //
  static time_point fromDate(int year= 0, int month= 0, int day= 0, 
                             int hour= 0, int min  = 0, int sec= 0,
                             int usec= 0);
  //
  // convert time_point to a date/time representation
  //
  static void toDate(const time_point &tp,
                     int &year, int &month, int &day,
                     int &hour, int &min, int &sec,
                     int &usec);

  // NOT Supported, we don't need current time. We only
  // want to represent UTC DateTime
  // static time_point now(); 
};

using UTCTime = std::chrono::time_point<UTCClock, std::chrono::microseconds>;
```

`utctime.cpp`

```
#include "utctime.h"
#include <ctime>

namespace chrono = std::chrono;
using chrono::duration_cast;
using chrono::time_point_cast; 

namespace {

std::time_t to_time_t(const UTCClock::time_point &tp) noexcept
{
  return std::time_t(
      duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(tp.time_since_epoch()).count());
}

UTCClock::time_point from_time_t(std::time_t tt) noexcept
{
  return time_point_cast<UTCClock::duration>(
     chrono::time_point<UTCClock,chrono::seconds>(chrono::seconds(tt)));
}

} // namespace


UTCClock::time_point UTCClock::fromDate(
    int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min, int sec, int usec)
{
  std::tm tm     = {0};
  tm.tm_year     = year - 1900;
  tm.tm_mon      = month - 1;
  tm.tm_mday     = day;
  tm.tm_hour     = hour;
  tm.tm_min      = min;
  tm.tm_sec      = sec;
  tm.tm_isdst    = -1;
  std::time_t tt = timegm(&tm);
  return from_time_t(tt) + chrono::microseconds(usec);
}

void UTCClock::toDate(const UTCClock::time_point &tp,
                      int &year,
                      int &month,
                      int &day,
                      int &hour,
                      int &min,
                      int &sec,
                      int &usec)
{
  std::time_t tt = to_time_t(tp);
  std::tm tm;
  gmtime_r(&tt, &tm);
  year  = tm.tm_year + 1900;
  month = tm.tm_mon + 1;
  day   = tm.tm_mday;
  hour  = tm.tm_hour;
  min   = tm.tm_min;
  chrono::microseconds leftover =
      tp - from_time_t(tt) + chrono::seconds(tm.tm_sec);
  sec = duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(leftover).count();
  usec = (leftover-chrono::seconds(sec)).count();
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
#include "utctime.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  //
  // use UTCClock::fromDate to generate a UTCTime 
  //
  UTCTime t1 = UTCClock::fromDate(1901, 1,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  UTCTime t2 = UTCClock::fromDate(1901, 1,  1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

  //
  // Then we can make use of std::chrono algebra like
  // subtracting time_point 
  //
  microseconds timeDiff = t2 -t1; 

  std::cout << "t2-t1 difference in microseconds " << 
    timeDiff.count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "t2-t1 difference in hours " <<
    duration_cast<hours>(timeDiff).count() << std::endl;

  //
  // ...or adding/subtracting a duration to a time_point
  //    
  UTCTime t3 = t1 - minutes{3};
  std::cout << "t3-t1 difference in minutes " <<
    duration_cast<minutes>(t3-t1).count() << std::endl;

  t3 = t1 + milliseconds{123};
  std::cout << "t3-t1 difference in milliseconds " <<
    duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3-t1).count() << std::endl;

  //
  // ...we can also compare time_points
  //    
  if ( t3 > t1 ) std::cout <<  "t3 is greater than t1" << std::endl;

  //
  // We can get a date/time back from a time_point with UTCClock::toDate
  //
  int year, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec;
  UTCClock::toDate(t3, year, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec);

  //
  // std::chrono is also type safe and doesn't allow to
  // mix dates generated by different clocks
  //
  system_clock::time_point systp = system_clock::now();

  // NO: doesn't compile
  //  auto tx = t1 - systp;

  // NO: doesn't compile
  //  if (t1 < systp);

  // NO: doesn't compile
  // UTCClock::toDate(systp, year, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> t2-t1 difference in microseconds 3600000000
> t2-t1 difference in hours 1
> t3-t1 difference in minutes -3
> t3-t1 difference in milliseconds 123
> t3 is greater than t1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Just fyi, here is how this looks in C++20...

```
using UTCTime = std::chrono::time_point<UTCClock, std::chrono::microseconds>;
```

becomes:

```
using UTCTime = std::chrono::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds>;
```

---

This:

```
//
// use UTCClock::fromDate to generate a UTCTime 
//
UTCTime t1 = UTCClock::fromDate(1901, 1,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
UTCTime t2 = UTCClock::fromDate(1901, 1,  1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

becomes:

```
UTCTime t1 = sys_days{1901y/1/1};
UTCTime t2 = sys_days{1901y/1/1} + 1h;
```

---

This:

```
//
// Then we can make use of std::chrono algebra like
// subtracting time_point 
//
microseconds timeDiff = t2 -t1;
std::cout << "t2-t1 difference in microseconds " << timeDiff.count() << std::endl;
std::cout << "t2-t1 difference in hours " << duration_cast<hours>(timeDiff).count() << std::endl;
```

becomes:

```
//
// Then we can make use of std::chrono algebra like
// subtracting time_point 
//
microseconds timeDiff = t2 - t1; 
std::cout << "t2-t1 difference in microseconds " << timeDiff << '\n';
std::cout << "t2-t1 difference in hours " << duration_cast<hours>(timeDiff) << '\n';
```

---

This:

```
//
// ...or adding/subtracting a duration to a time_point
//    
UTCTime t3 = t1 - minutes{3};
std::cout << "t3-t1 difference in minutes " << duration_cast<minutes>(t3-t1).count() << std::endl;

t3 = t1 + milliseconds{123};
std::cout << "t3-t1 difference in milliseconds "
          << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3-t1).count() << std::endl;
```

becomes:

```
//
// ...or adding/subtracting a duration to a time_point
//    
UTCTime t3 = t1 - 3min;
std::cout << "t3-t1 difference in minutes " << duration_cast<minutes>(t3-t1) << '\n';

t3 = t1 + 123ms;
std::cout << "t3-t1 difference in milliseconds "
          << duration_cast<milliseconds>(t3-t1) << '\n';
```

---

This:

```
//
// ...we can also compare time_points
//    
if ( t3 > t1 ) std::cout <<  "t3 is greater than t1" << std::endl;
```

remains unchanged.

---

This:

```
//
// We can get a date/time back from a time_point with UTCClock::toDate
//
int year, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec;
UTCClock::toDate(t3, year, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec);
```

becomes:

```
//
// We can get a date/time back from a time_point with UTCClock::toDate
//
auto td = floor<days>(t3);
year_month_day ymd = td;
hh_mm_ss hms{t3-td};
```

`ymd` has getters for year, month and day, and `hms` has getters for hours, minutes, seconds and microseconds.

---

The output changes from:

```
t2-t1 difference in microseconds 3600000000
t2-t1 difference in hours 1
t3-t1 difference in minutes -3
t3-t1 difference in milliseconds 123
t3 is greater than t1
```

to:

```
t2-t1 difference in microseconds 3600000000µs
t2-t1 difference in hours 1h
t3-t1 difference in minutes -3min
t3-t1 difference in milliseconds 123ms
t3 is greater than t1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. I wish I could use c++20 right away, but I need to be compatible with old OS at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are storing date and time information with millisecond precision, then you can always do:

```cpp
time_point<system_clock, milliseconds> epoch_milli{};
auto one_million_millisecond_from_epoch = epoch_milli + milliseconds(1'000'000);
```